# How to have the camera take a picture and not show you the preview?

Tags: android, google-glass

I just want to launch the camera activity and have it return to the calling activity. Basically I don't care about seeing the preview image where you "tap to select".

The reason for this is I'm trying to inject tap events, so I cannot get past this screen because you can't inject events into the Camera application.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to capture the image using [Camera.takePicture()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#takePicture%28android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback%29%22Camera.takePicture%28%29%22)?  The last parameter is a callback with the bytes of the image captured.  You can then create a bitmap with the byte array and save it to a file:

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

FilenameOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
fos.close();
```

I haven't used this without a preview, but you might be able to open the camera and call takePicture() without having to use the preview.